# Random access of a linked list element

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

In an [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/) about linked list, it is said that accessing a random element is not allowed and to access a certain node we need to traverse it from the head node

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
 
// This function prints contents of linked list
// starting from the given node
void printList(Node* n)
{
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->data << " ";
        n = n->next;
    }
}
 
// Driver code
int main()
{
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* second = NULL;
    Node* third = NULL;
 
    // allocate 3 nodes in the heap
    head = new Node();
    second = new Node();
    third = new Node();
 
    head->data = 1; // assign data in first node
    head->next = second; // Link first node with second
 
    second->data = 2; // assign data to second node
    second->next = third;
 
    third->data = 3; // assign data to third node
    third->next = NULL;
 
    printList(head);
 
    return 0;
}
```

This was the example code on traversing a linked list and printing it's values

If i change the argument of `printList()` to `second`, it would still work

My question is, did i misinterpret the meaning to "access an element of a linkedlist", what does an element of a linkedlist contain?

Comment: It's not that it's not allowed, it can't be done in a single O(1) mechanism.  The article mentioned implementing a binary search - basically looking at the element "half way" through the list.  You have to iterate the list one by one to access the "nth" element - there is no direct access to the nth element in O(1).

Comment: I **think** you misinterpreted "access an element of a linked list", as it is describing how to access an element that you don't already have access to.  Since you have a pointer named `second`, you can access it.  If you did not have that pointer, you would need to traverse the list to find the second element.

Comment: “Random Access” means that you can instantly access any element with simple pointer arithmetic. A linked list can’t do that, you have to follow the chain to get to the Nth element.

Comment: @DrewDormann this is my first introduction to data structures and linked lists, but is it common for us to not have access to the element?

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- That site you linked to has C++ code that is not good.  Do not use this header.  Instead `#include` the correct, standard C++ headers.

Comment: @RandyTunru it is uncommon to have a named pointer to every element in a container.  Arguably, that defeats the purpose of the container.  Imagine modifying this program so the list contains 10000 elements, instead of 3.  You would not want to create 10000 distinct named variables.  You would not want such a simple program to require more than 30000 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you overinterpreted the article. You should store in your program only pointer to the first element (head) and in that case, you are not able to access n-th element directly. You need to find it "manually" by jumping to "next" element (n-1) times.

It doesn't mean that you are not able to access n-th element if you have pointer to that element.

Comment: is it actually common for us to not have pointers to the element?

Comment: @RandyTunru If it is, a list is probably the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 1):

> accessing a random element is not allowed

That statement isn't quite precise about linked lists.

What is true is that given a linked list (and nothing more), it isn't possible **find** an element at any given index in constant time.

However, if you have an iterator or a reference to an element of a list, you can access that element in constant time through the iterator / reference.

Answer (score 0):

To clear your confusion we probably should add the example of an array

Say we have an array

`[1,2,3,4,5]`

and a linkedlist

`1->2->3->4->5`

now if you want to access the 5th element in both the data structure what can you do

for array you just have to access the array[4] to get the element which is a O(1) operation to get the element

but for linkedList this doesn't happen

for accessing the 5th element of the linkedList you ll have to iterate in a manner like this

```
int element = 5;
while(element--){
   head = head->next;
}
and when the loop ends you ll get your element
```